# Set AutoScrollPosition of horizontal scrollbar on tabpage

Tags: vb.net, autoscroll, tabpage

I have a tabcontrol that has a tabpage that I've added autoscroll to via the properties window. When the scrollbars appear, the horizontal scrollbar is automatically scrolled all the way to the right. This is the exact opposite of what I need, when the horizontal scrollbar appears, I need it to be automically scrolled all the way to the left. How do I do this? I've been tinkering with AutoScrollPosition, but it doesn't seem to do anything...most likely user error on my part. Any advice? I haven't been able to find anything on the net that's been helpful.

I'm using vb.net

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoscroll position is relative to its current position you'll need to find the current position and then take that away.

`tabpage1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(-tabpage1.AutoScrollPosition.X, 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but could you elaborate a little more? How do I find the current position? It's going to be different depending on the user's screen size and resolution

Comment: Actually, forget about it. I've determined that my scrollbar is scrolling to the right because I'm moving a panel to the far right of my screen. I'll just move it to the center of the screen instead and that will take care of it. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, code above shows how to get position, use `AutoScrollPosition.X` for horizontal and `AutoScrollPosition.Y` for vertical.